# How can i search for string in multiple line string variable? C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I save an output of a command from console.

The output can have more than one line.

How can I search for specific words in all the output ?

Here is my current code:

```
string buff, ok; 
ok = "OK"; 
SerialPort p = ...
// p initialization...
p.Write("AT+CMGL=\"REC UNREAD\" " + "\r"); 
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); 
buff = p.ReadExisting(); 
if (buff.Contains(ok)) 
   // do smth
```

an example of the output:

```
+CMGL: 10,"REC READ","0372022244",,"12/02/22,08:08:58+08"
2073692066616374757261207661206669206163686974617461206C612074696D702120446574616C696920696E206D6167617A696E656C6520566F6461666F6E6520736175206C612062616E6361206476732E

OK
```

will this search all the lines from buff for ok ? or just the first line ? i tried it like this and it seems that he can not find "OK" in the output

```
    namespace SerialTest

{
    public class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string buff="0";
            string ok = "OK";

            SerialPort p = new SerialPort("COM28");
            p.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(p_DataReceived);
            p.Open();
            string line = "1";
            p.Write("AT" + "\r");
            buff = p.ReadExisting();
            p.Write("AT+CMGF=1"+ "\r" );
            buff = p.ReadExisting();

            do
            {
                p.Write("AT+CMGL=\"REC UNREAD\" " + "\r");
                buff = p.ReadExisting();

                if (buff.Contains(ok))
                    Console.WriteLine("Everything is OK");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("NOK");

                line = Console.ReadLine();
            } while (line != "quit");
            p.Close();
        }

        public static void p_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine((sender as SerialPort).ReadExisting());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? This is not difficult, so please explain what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: string buff,ok;
ok="OK";
p.Write("AT+CMGL=\"REC UNREAD\" " + "\r");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
buff = p.ReadExisting();
if (buff.Contains(ok))
do smth

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and add the code sample to it.

Comment: Please explain what is not working with this piece of code. Looks like it should work just fine.

Comment: o.k.  `sleep()` is never a good option...

Comment: There are no issues with that code

Comment: What is the value of `ok`? We have no idea if it is in the output string if you don't show us what it is. You have also not shown where the linebreaks are in the output.

Comment: Are you using serial communications?

Comment: I updated your code to show that you are using a `SerialPort`

Comment: Yes, i am using serial communication.
@Oded i have added the output of the command in the question, the last line of the output is "OK"

Comment: Could you show us how exactly you created the output? Could you give us the output of `Console.WriteLine("buff: \"{0}\"\nok: \"{1}\", buff, ok);`?

Comment: Here is the output: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/690/capturelcmr.png/

Comment: If you put `if(buff.Contains(ok)) { ... }` where you put this, it should work.

Comment: As you can see from here: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/18/capturevxk.png/ 
Sometimes buff is empty..

Comment: Then you should be asking another question. You asked if you can search for a string across a multi-line string and the answer is 'yes'. You should be asking why your buffer is empty sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p.ReadExisting()` does read operations on a `SerialPort`.

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting.aspx) documentation says:

> Reads all immediately available bytes, based on the encoding, in both
>   the stream and the input buffer of the SerialPort object.

This means that you might not get all the data you are expecting in one single call to `ReadExisting` as that data might not ba available yet. You should probably loop through and read all the data from the serial port before doing the `Contains` check.

On a side note: using `Thread.Sleep` especially when dealing with serial operations is not a good idea. Instead of sleeping while waiting for the data, use the `SerialPort.DataReceived` [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived) to read available data.

Try this to correctly read data from your serial port and get rid of the `Sleep`

```
String data = "";
p.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
   string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
   data += indata;
}
```

And then have a timer set to check the output after 1 second.
In the timer event handler you check `data.Contains("OK");`

Comment: Yes, the data is read from SerialPort, isnt the sleep enough for the data to be avaiable ?

Comment: @AlexisCimpu No because if you receive a lot of data while sleeping, the OS will discard them in case the internal buffers are full which will end up in data loss

Comment: I have added all the code, i was already using EventHandler, am i using them wrong?

Comment: @AlexisCimpu There are a couple of things that need to be fixed but are out of this question's scope (multithreading). If you find my answer helpful as why you are not receiving all your text then please mark it as an answer and then post another question on reading and writing into serial ports.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968024/why-the-buffer-is-empty here is the other questions.. at first i thought maybe i was searching wrongly, i have created another questions for the actual problem.

Comment: Thanks, I posted an answer to your question there

Answer (score 0):

`buff.Contains(ok)` will search the entire string (`buff`) for your specified string (`ok`).

A new line character (`'\n'`) is treated in the same way as any other character in the string.
If you had a string with value `"a\nb\nc"` and you were to search for `"\nc"`, it would return true, as the string contains a string that consists of the characters `'\n'` and `'c'`.

So if this is not working for you, I would recheck the value of `buff` and `ok`, because this code should be fine.