# Why the buffer is empty?

Tags: c#, serial-communication

I am trying to check some values some AT commands ran on a GSM modem.
I am stuck at the point where when trying to check if the output of a command contains some values is true or not.

Using the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;


namespace SerialTest
{
    public class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string buff="0";
            string ok = "OK";

            SerialPort p = new SerialPort("COM28");
            p.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(p_DataReceived);
            p.Open();
            string line = "1";
            p.Write("AT" + "\r");
            buff = p.ReadExisting();
            Console.WriteLine("buff: \"{0}\"\nok: \"{1}\"", buff, ok);
            p.Write("AT+CMGF=1"+ "\r" );
            buff = p.ReadExisting();
            Console.WriteLine("buff: \"{0}\"\nok: \"{1}\"", buff, ok);
            do
            {
                p.Write("AT+CMGL=\"REC UNREAD\" " + "\r");
                buff = p.ReadExisting(); 
                Console.WriteLine("buff: \"{0}\"\nok: \"{1}\"", buff, ok);
                /*if (buff.Contains(ok))
                    Console.WriteLine("Everything is OK");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("NOK");*/
                line = Console.ReadLine();
            } while (line != "quit");
            p.Close();
        }

        public static void p_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine((sender as SerialPort).ReadExisting());
        }
    }
}
```

I get this output:

[image]

Why is it that sometimes buff is empty and is displayed later ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are calls to `ReadExisting()` that are superfluous.
You should not be reading your serial port output in the main method, let the event handler do the work for you.
Also, you should append what you read in the event handler to the `buff` variable so that you can all the data received when you check your buffer.

Try this instead:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ModemReader r = new ModemReader();
        r.StartReading();
    }
    class ModemReader{
        string buff="";
        public void StartReading()
        {
            string ok = "OK";
            SerialPort p = new SerialPort("COM28");
            p.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(p_DataReceived);
            p.Open();
            string line = "1";
            p.Write("AT" + "\r");
            Console.WriteLine("buff: \"{0}\"\nok: \"{1}\"", buff, ok);
            p.Write("AT+CMGF=1"+ "\r" );
            Console.WriteLine("buff: \"{0}\"\nok: \"{1}\"", buff, ok);
            do
            {
                // Clear the buffer here
                buff = "";  

                p.Write("AT+CMGL=\"REC UNREAD\" " + "\r");
                Console.WriteLine("buff: \"{0}\"\nok: \"{1}\"", buff, ok);
                if (buff.Contains(ok))
                    Console.WriteLine("Everything is OK");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("NOK");
                line = Console.ReadLine();
            } while (line != "quit");
            p.Close();
        }
        public void p_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string s = (sender as SerialPort).ReadExisting();
            buff += s;
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, but the problem is that the while structure will run continuously until the program is stopped, the while structure is checking if there is any unread messages on the modem and if there is another command will be sent. if i append all the output, when i do the check the buff will have previous entries as well.

Comment: 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'SerialTest.Program.buff' 27 61
2 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'SerialTest.Program.buff' 30 61
3 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'SerialTest.Program.buff' 35 65
4 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'SerialTest.Program.buff' 49 13

Comment: The loop will write `p.Write("AT+CMGL=\"REC UNREAD\" " + "\r");` all the time and the "OK" will never be found, is this what you want? Or do you want to write data to the port from the consol (user input)?

Comment: i want for the loop to send this command p.Write("AT+CMGL=\"REC UNREAD\" " + "\r"); and check if the output contains the "+40755555555" for example, this is how i know if there is any new messages on the modem from 40755555555, after i run the command above the message will be marked as read by the modem.

Comment: 1 Method must have a return type 19 16

Comment: I get different results..
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/411/capture1i.png/
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/209/captureoeo.png/

Comment: Might be due to the fact that the buffer is not cleared before the loop, check my edit

Comment: when i was executing the latest code, it was only going on the NOK side and also the buff was sometimes empty sometimes with the output.
i have added again a sleep of 1 sec after every command and it seems to be working fine even after several runs.
do you believe that the sleep could affect the output later ? (i still have to finish the code)

Answer (score 0):

You can only consume the port data once. Because you consume it inside your handler, it is no longer present when you try to put it in your buffer.

Comment: but after every command i am reading all the data(input and output) shouldn't i have it in buff when i am writing it to console ?

Comment: `ReadExisting()` clears out the port's buffer. You can't know when your handler will execute (I'm assuming you have `ReceivedBytesThreshold` set to default value of 1), so sometimes it will consume the data before you main loop and sometimes it won't. I would recommend you either remove your handler, or if you need to keep it, have it copy the consumed data in a buffer you can use in the main loop.